# upload file directly when selected with upload script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form

```css
*{
    color: white;
}

.upload_container{
 background-color: #12161C;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width: 960px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.upload_container > .upload_form{

}

input[type="file"]{
    display: none;
}

.upload_button{
    padding: 9.5px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #299219;
 color: white;
 border: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #354F9C;
}

.upload_button:hover{
 background-color: #4F66AC;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload_container">
 <form class="upload_form">
  <h2 class="h2_header">Upload your image</h2>
  <label for="upload_file" class="upload_button">
      Choose an image
  </label>
  <input id="upload_file" type="file"/>
 </form>
</div>
```

Now I want that if someone has chosen an image that the image will directly uploaded without pressing a button. How can I call something like this? Because I never did this and I dont know how to do something like that. It would be nice if you can give me some keywords to search or a link.

Comment: Look into [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It does exactly what you want.

Here are some more javasripts handling fileuploads. Just google for it!

FineUploader, jQuery File Uploader, YUI3 Uploader, FancyUpload, MooUpload, Plupload, Dropzone